# What are the Grails bugs that developers have to work around?

Tags: grails, groovy

In some of the articles I've read, and some of the podcasts I've heard, people have been saying they need to work around a number of bugs existing in Grails.

As a beginner Grails developer, how will I know what those bugs are ( so that I wouldn't have to waste time researching them )? Are they listed somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try looking at the [Grails Jira.](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS?report=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:changelog-panel)

Comment: a bit unwieldy to read thru - its more of a reference, useful when you see behaviour that is unexpected and suspect its a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced problems with Grails on non-Oracle versions of the JDK, such as IBM's.  It's been quite an experience trying to get a small Grails application to build using IBM's JDK and run on Websphere 7.  One recent problem has been that the webxml plugin causes an exception in IBM's SAXParser, which is built into rt.jar, which is the very first jar the JVM loads and thus it is practically intrinsic to the language.  We are working on a solution.

Comment: Tough one indeed. Good luck, and let us know of your progress :)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem I have had with Grails is every time I upgraded to a new version, it seems to break things that were previously working. If you are using extra plugins, you should be even more careful. Most of these problems are pretty minor ones and you can easily find a workaround once you know whats going on.
If you are considering Grails, be ready to spend 20% of the time fighting with Grails in exchange for the higher productivity it provides.